# Debugging Halloween Sale : Hackerrank

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The idea is to apply a linear incremented discount until you hit the `m` value then all the next purchases are the `m`

[Link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/halloween-sale/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

seems very easy but my approach is not covering some edge-cases.

**Example:**

**Input:**

> 16, 2, 1, 9981

**Output:**

> 9918

**Expected Output:**

> 9917

what am I missing?

A better approach is also highly appreciated

```js
// tried on (20,3,6,80) works like charm
function howManyGames(p, d, m, s) {
    // Return the number of games you can buy
    if(s<p) return 0
    let remaining = s-p
    let max = p
    let min = m
    let count = 1
    while(remaining > min && max > min) {
        count++
        max-=d
        remaining -= max
    }
    return count + (m !==0?Math.floor(remaining/m): 0)
}
```

**Problem Description:**

> You wish to buy video games from the famous online video game store
> Mist.
>
> Usually, all games are sold at the same price, `p`dollars. However,
> they are planning to have the seasonal Halloween Sale next month in
> which you can buy games at a cheaper price. Specifically, the first
> game you buy during the sale will be sold at `p`dollars, but every
> subsequent game you buy will be sold at exactly `d`dollars less than
> the cost of the previous one you bought. This will continue until the
> cost becomes less than or equal to `m`dollars, after which every game
> you buy will cost `m`dollars each.
>
> For example,

> if p=20 , d=3 , m=6,

> then the following are the costs of the first 11 games you buy, in order:

> `20, 17, 14, 11, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6`
>
> You have `s` dollars in your Mist wallet. How many games can you buy during the Halloween Sale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error:**

```
while(remaining > min && max > min) {
        count++
        max-=d
        remaining -= max
    }
```

> **max > min**

When you are doing this operation, you are not comparing the current maximum with the minimum, else you are comparing the maximum of the last operation with the minimum.

Also, the remaining should always be greater than the max value.

And you can't buy an item at the cost of m if max is greater than m.

Take a look at the code below, which passes all the test cases.

```js
// Complete the how many games function below.
function howManyGames(p, d, m, s) {
    // Return the number of games you can buy
    if(s<p) return 0
    let remaining = s
    let max = p
    let min = m
    let count = 0
    while(remaining > min && max > min && remaining > max) {
        count++
        remaining -= max
        max-=d
    }
    if(max > m)
        return count
    return count + (m !== 0 ? Math.floor(remaining/m): 0)
}
```